# Getting ids_for_pages from Graph returns empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm having some trouble connecting people across apps and bots in messenger.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/connecting-accounts

I've already associated my developers facebook app (with a Facebook log in and Messenger Products) in Business, as well as the page.

My objective is in my server being able to identify the messenger user with the log in user in the app. So when the user would go to the messenger would have the same experience as in the app.

The trouble is: when I try to get `ids_for_pages` from graph it returns the data empty, even after this user talks to the bot.

**Graph GET (v2.10)**

```
/{user_login_id}/ids_for_pages?access_token={user_login_access_token}&appsecret_proof={appsecret_proof}

{"data": []}
```

When I'm using the Page-Scoped ID I'm able to get `ids_for_apps` (great I can use that to match the user if the user already log in to my app), but if the user talks to the bot and then goes to my app I see no way for me to match the user.
I also investigated on Business Mapping API with the `token_for_business` but it is necessary the user node. Great in the app but I can't get the user token or user node by the Page-Scoped ID.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Am I doing something wrong? A missing permission? My bot is live and has `pages_messaging`.

Any guidance helps! Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**

As amuramoto said, I was using the wrong `access_token`. It must be the same as I used in the `ids_for_apps`.

```
/{user_login_id}/ids_for_pages?access_token={page_access_token}&appsecret_proof={appsecret_proof}
```

Comment: Are you using the right access token? The example in the docs show that called to `ids_for_pages` requires a [app acess token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens), not the user access token.

Comment: The timing was almost perfect! A few tests and reads later I notice that as well. Indeed it wasn't the right token!!! I was taking the login token as the access_token which was wrong. Since there was no error message I didn't noticed.

Thanks anyway for your answer amuramoto! You are absolutely correct!

Comment: here user_login_id means which id? graph id or app id? also how can you generate appsecret_proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this here in case this questions comes up for anyone in the future.

You aren't using the right access token. The example in the docs show that calls to `ids_for_pages` requires a page-scoped access token, not the user access token.

Comment: I'm think im using the a page access token, but having the same issue. The result is an empty data for other users, but not for me.How to know if the token I'm using is a page access token?

Comment: @Diego PSID either comes from the [app settings UI](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/setup#page_access_token) or via [POST request to the API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens). You can also see what permissions are scoped to your token with the [access token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken)

Comment: When I use an APP access token on "{user-page-id}/ids_for_pages" the api returns the Messenger Sender ID ok. That means the user has an ID on "both sides (page and messenger)". But when I use the PAGE access token on "{messenger-sender-id}/ids_for_apps&appsecret_proof" it returns empty for other users, but the page id for me. Any ideas? Thanks